# How do I monitor the progress of URLConnection.getInputStream() in Android where javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream() is unavailable?

Tags: android

I am uploading an image to a server.

```
URLConnection connection;

/* set up the connection parameters */
```

And finally, upload the file to the server via,

```
connection.getInputStream();
```

I need to show a horizontal `ProgressBar` that will display the upload progress. So how do I find the progress of `URLConnection.getInputStream();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check progress of URLconnection.getInputStream()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161514/is-it-possible-to-check-progress-of-urlconnection-getinputstream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your uploading process into AsyncTask. So, you'll have uploading in `doInBackground()`, where you can upload your image "by parts" (actually, with some buffer), and after each portion is downloaded call `publishProgress()`. In `onProgressUpdate()` method you have ability to update your ui with the new progress state. You can update your progress bar, or set new percent value to TextView - do what you want.

Comment: Yes, that was the original plan. But how do I set the "percent value." Since the uploading is done by the statement connection.getInputStream() I can't find the amount of data that has been sent to the server.

Comment: Atually, if you're _uploading_ image, you have to use `connection.getOutputStream();`. Then, you can compress your bitmap using ByteArrayOutputStream, get resulting byte[] from this, and load to server "by parts" (i mean, using `write(byte[] b, int offset, int length)`) with progress update, after each step. You'll know, how many percents have you uploaded (you know whole image size, and size of uploaded part). Also, you can look at original ProgressMonitorInputStream [source](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.java.htm), they have similar behavior:

Comment: Thank you for that. the `write(byte[] b, int offset, int length)` part helped. I however used http://rainbowlibs.googlecode.com/svn-history/r94/android/trunk/rainbowlibs/src/it/rainbowbreeze/libs/data/HttpMultipartClient.java to do the multi-part POST, and it wrote data to the server "by parts." Showing the progress bar was easy.