# Show progress bar while uploading file to dropbox by publishProgress

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

In my application,I have written code to upload a file to dropbox.I am successfully able to do that.I want to show Progressbar while file is being uploaded.I have implemented onProgressUpdate method in my Asynctask class.But I am not getting how to calculate value that I will pass in publishProgress method in doInBackground().Or How can I get the value that I will pass in publish progress method.I am using below code which is part of DropBox API in my doInBackGround method.

```
   File file = new File("working-draft.txt");
   FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/magnum-opus.txt", inputStream,
   file.length(), null, null); 
   Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
```

Kindly provide your suggestions for above query.Thanx :)

Comment: i also done with this from amazon but i used intent service for this

Comment: You can probably use the same concept as suggested here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9117200/976367

Answer (score 1):

It's too late, but surely will help others
The Dropbox API v2 Java SDK now offers progress listeners for uploads and downloads. This has been released in [v3.0.9](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/releases/tag/v3.0.9):

You can use the `ProgressListner` by this:

```
dbxClient.files().uploadBuilder("/" + file.getName()) //Path in the user's Dropbox to save the file.
                .withMode(WriteMode.ADD)
                .uploadAndFinish(inputStream, new IOUtil.ProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesWritten) {
                        percentWritten =(bytesWritten/uploadFile.length())*100;      //Progress Percentage
                    }
                });
```

Cheers. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

After some R & D,I finally got the solution from [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/ProgressListener.html)

Instead of passing null to the last argument of putFile method,I implemented Progress Listener and got the values of number of bytes transferred through onProgress method.

Thanx for suggesting your answers. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class uploadfile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
    {

         private ProgressDialog dialog;
            protected Context mContext;
            long totalSize;

          public uploadfile(Context context) {

                mContext = context;
            }

         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                dialog.setTitle("Chance");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                //dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setMessage("uploading...");
                dialog.show();
                //dialog.setProgress(0);

            }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your url");
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy);
             String responseMessage = "";


            try {

                 CustomMultiPartEntity entity = new CustomMultiPartEntity(new ProgressListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void transferred(long num) {
                         publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                     }
                 });




            //post request to send the file

            FileBody file1 = new FileBody(new File("path of file"));
            entity.addPart("file", file1);
            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();

            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // DEBUG
            System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, httpContext);
            responseMessage = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println( "Server response" + responseMessage );




            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                responseMessage = "unreachable";

            }

            catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                responseMessage = "unreachable";

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                responseMessage = "unreachable";

            }

            return responseMessage;


        }


         @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                dialog.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
            }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

             //result is the response back from "doInBackground"
            dialog.cancel();


            //check if there were errors upoloading
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("unreachable")) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error while uploading...Please check your internet connection and retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

           if(result.equals("[\"uploaded\"]"))
           {
               Toast.makeText(mContext, "uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               finish();
           }




        }

    }
```

CustomMultiPartEntity.java

```
public class CustomMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity
   {

private final ProgressListener listener;

public CustomMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener)
{
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
}

public CustomMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode, final ProgressListener listener)
{
    super(mode);
    this.listener = listener;
}

public CustomMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary, final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener)
{
    super(mode, boundary, charset);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException
{
    super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
}

public static interface ProgressListener
{
    void transferred(long num);
}

public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream
{

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private long transferred;

    public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out, final ProgressListener listener)
    {
        super(out);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.transferred = 0;
    }

    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        this.transferred += len;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        out.write(b);
        this.transferred++;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }
}
  }
```