# Android when AsyncTask Process if no internet found how to give warning "please connect internet"

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Android AsyncTask processing and found no internet connection system give warning "user please connect internet". How can I do this in my code?

Another problem is when internet not connected its show loading but I don't go back page. How to solve this problem?

I don't understand how to do this inside this code.

```
public class data extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://orangehostbd.com/app/bpl2/index.php";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(data.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    data.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Helper` class.
   Inside this class, create a method to check internet connection.

   ```
   public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
       final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
       return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
   }
   ```
2. Inside your activity class, use above `isNetworkConnected()` method in `doInBackground`.

   ```
   if (Helper.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
        // do your stuff
   } else{
       Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your internet connection is lost.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```
3. Use this permission in `Manifest` file.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```

Comment: `Toast.makeText(...)`inside `doInBackground(...)` outside the gui-thread is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "how to display warning inside doInBackground" because you are not allowed to access the gui inside doInBackground technically you can use the [progress indicator of asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517641/publishprogress-from-inside-a-function-in-doinbackground) to transfer a message to the gui.

However i would recommond a differen aproach: either

- [check for problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789612/how-can-i-check-whether-an-android-device-is-connected-to-the-web) **before** starting the async task
- or let the async task stop and return with an error as described by @Muthukrishnan Rajendran